# Is it possible to create a table view without subclassing tableView UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I already have a view controller, is it possible to attach a table view on top of the current view, without the needed to create a subclass of UITableViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just set up the table view like any other view and connect it to your viewcontroller by setting the `delegate` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) and `dataSource` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) - properties. See the references on which method you have to implement in your viewcontroller in order to get things working.